# How to change the background color of a span/div WITHOUT CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm building an alert page. I'm trying to make the page work even if javascript and CSS is failing.

I would like to use maybe deprecate HTML codes to do this. I need the span that contains the alert message to have a red background.

Please advise.

Comment: Why do you expect your CSS to fail? You can use an inline style, but you're still technically using CSS.

Comment: Maybe the audience is a developer and was debugging the page and forgot to turn the CSS back on the next day.

Comment: Wouldn't that be immediately obvious when they see the unstyled page? I can't imagine a single scenario where that would be necessary. HTML structures data. CSS styles data. Simple as that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by css failing? Css is rendered by browsers....http://www.ehow.com/how_10001369_disable-css-chrome.html go here, and follow the steps in reverse to activate it again..I cannot imagine any user doing this and expecting a styled page :)

Comment: I mean the audience are web developers and they debug web pages from time to time, so they used debugging tool and turned CSS OFF. Then next day they forgot to turn it back on and they did not notice the alert in a styled way. Why is this so complicated?

Comment: What if the debugging tool fails? You will seek a way to debug without debugging tool?

Comment: If debugging tool fails, I cannot debug. If alert fails, I need to rethink again how to minimize risks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `bgcolor` attribute to set the background colour, but it's far better to use CSS to style a page as the `bgcolor` attribute only works on certain tags.

```
<table bgcolor="#FF0000"><tr><td> My alert contents </td></tr></table>
```

For example it won't work on `<span>`, `<div>` or `<p>` tags, but will work on `<body>` and `<table>` tags.

Answer (score 10):

Try this :D
Example:

```
<div style="background-color:red"> </div>
```

You must insert the name of color like red, blue and so on.

Comment: thanks for your help but that is a CSS inline styling

Comment: @RiccardoOsmosit You're not just limited to named colours, you can use RGB values as well.

Comment: Yep RGB works fine just fine. Thank you guys, you are truly problem solvers and are making constructive suggestions here at stackoverflow.